# How do I find $\sum_{k=2}^nk(k-1)\binom{n}{k}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, binomial-theorem

I have come across the following problem in my textbook and I am looking for some help with its execution, thanks!

Find,

$$\sum_{k=2}^nk(k-1)\binom{n}{k}$$

Comment: Are you allowed to utilize the differentiation $$ \frac{d^2}{dx^2}(1+x)^n = \sum_{k=2}^{n} \binom{n}{k} k(k-1)x^{k-2} $$?

Comment: whatever way to find it yes, could you show this?

Comment: I tried to use the binomial theorem but got stucl

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a good way to get this to look more like the binomial theorem.

Expand $$ \dbinom nk = \dfrac {n!}{k!(n-k)!} $$

Then $$ k(k-1) \dbinom nk = \dfrac {n!}{(k-2)!(n-k)!} = n(n-1)\dfrac {(n-2)!}{(k-2)!(n-k)!} = n(n-1)\dbinom {n-2}{k-2}$$

Now the $n(n-1)$ can be pulled out of the sum, so the sum becomes

$$ n(n-1)\sum_{k=2}^n \dbinom{n-2}{k-2} = n(n-1)\sum_{j=0}^{n-2} \dbinom{n-2}j$$

where I used the change of variables $j = k-2$. You should be able to proceed with the binomial theorem.

Comment: what happens when you pull that term out?

Comment: @mt12345 Edited.

Comment: then I just need to use the binomial theorem to complete it?

Comment: @mt12345 Correct!

Comment: thanks, i will try and complete this. Also does Bernards solution below make sense to you?

Comment: @mt12345 In my opinion it's a little less straightforward than mine, but it does make sense. If there's any part of the solution you want clarification on, you should probably comment on Bernard's answer. (I can respond there too.)

Comment: thanks! I am trying to work thro\ugh the binomial theorem part of your solution but I am getting a bit stuck

Comment: @mt12345 Where are you getting stuck? What have you been trying?

Comment: I'm not sure what I am doing to be honest

Comment: @mt12345 I'm going to move the discussion to chat then. Start by stating the binomial theorem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72787/discussion-between-y-forman-and-mt12345).

Answer (score 11):

You want to select $\geq 2$ people from a group of $n$ people, give a gold medal to someone in the selected crew and a silver medal to someone else in the crew. You may pick the gold medalist in $n$ ways, the silver medalist in $n-1$ ways and the other members of the crew in $2^{n-2}$ ways, so
$$ \sum_{k=2}^{n}k(k-1)\binom{n}{k} = n(n-1) 2^{n-2}.$$

---

In the standard generating-functions fashion, by applying $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$ to both sides of $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}x^k = (x+1)^n $ we get $\sum_{k=2}^{n}\binom{n}{k}k(k-1)x^{k-2} = n(n-1)(x+1)^{n-2}$ and the same outcome can be recovered by evaluating these terms at $x=1$.

Comment: would you be able to show this using binomial expansion or theorem? thanks for your post!

Comment: @mt12345: answer updated.

Answer (score 3):

A probabilistic approach. Let $p=1/2$ and let $X\sim \text{Bin}(n,p)$ so that $X\stackrel{d}{=}X_{1}+\dotsb+X_{n}$ where $X_{i}\sim\text{Ber}(p)$ are i.i.d Bernoulli trials. Then
$$
EX=\sum_{i=1}^n EX_{i}=np;\quad EX^2-(EX)^2=\text{Var} X=\sum_{i=1}^n \text{Var}X_{i}=np(1-p).
$$
by independence. Hence
$$
EX(X-1)=EX^2-EX=np(1-p)+(np)^2-np=p^2(n^2-n)=\frac{n^2-n}{4}.
$$
But
$$
\sum_{k=2}^nk(k-1)\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{2^n}=EX(X-1)\implies
\sum_{k=2}^nk(k-1)\binom{n}{k}=2^{n-2}n(n-1).
$$
Alternatively, use the identity
$$
\binom{n}{k}\binom{k}{2}=\binom{n}{2}\binom{n-2}{k-2};\quad n\geq k\geq 2
$$
so that
$$
\sum_{k=2}^nk(k-1)\binom{n}{k}=
\sum_{k=2}^n2\binom{k}{2}\binom{n}{k}=
2\binom{n}{2}\sum_{k=2}^n\binom{n-2}{k-2}
=n(n-1)2^{n-2}
$$
by the binomial theorem.

Comment: is this one solution,

Alternatively, use the identity
$$
\binom{n}{k}\binom{k}{2}=\binom{n}{2}\binom{n-2}{k-2};\quad n\geq k\geq 2
$$
so that
$$
\sum_{k=2}^nk(k-1)\binom{n}{k}=
\sum_{k=2}^n2\binom{k}{2}\binom{n}{k}=
2\binom{n}{2}\sum_{k=2}^n\binom{n-2}{k-2}
=n(n-1)2^{n-2}
$$
by the binomial theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Remember the binomial coefficient $\dbinom nk$ is  the coefficient of $x^k$ in the expansion of $(1+x)^n$. So $k(k-1)\dbinom nk$ is  the coefficient of $(x^k)''$ in the expansion of $\bigl((1+x)^n\bigr)''$:
$$\sum_{k=2}^nk(k-1)\dbinom nk x^{k-2}=n(n-1)(1+x)^{n-2},$$
and setting $x=1$ in this formula, you get
$$\sum_{k=2}^nk(k-1)\dbinom nk= n(n-1)2^{n-2}.$$

Comment: thanks for your submission!